# Wifi not working on Ubuntu 14.04 (using an external wifi adpater)

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, adapter

Yesterday, I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my lenovo laptop alongside windows 8.1 . Since then I have trouble using wifi on Ubuntu. I am using a **external** wifi adapter to run wifi on my windows and it is running as it used to run. Through that adapter I am not able to connect to the wifi on Ubuntu (although the signal seems pretty strong). When I try to connect it asks me the password and when I enter it, after sometime it again asks me the password. I have done this a lot of time but in vain. I am not sure whether it's a compatibility issue between my wifi adapter and Ubuntu.

Here is a link to this adapter in case someone want to know its properties - [www.amazon.in](http://www.amazon.in/TP-Link-TL-WN722N-150Mbps-Wireless-Adapter/dp/B002SZEOLG?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=4903ccc6-b7ca-47d6-8699-90bc4c79641d)

Here is the output of the **lsusb** command -

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:5728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 

Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0cf3:9271 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR9271 802.11n

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.